# Can't get pair from map value

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, std-pair

I have this structure

```
static map<TypeA, pair<reference_wrapper<TypeB>, TypeC>> my_map;
```

Later, I access it like this:

```
pair<reference_wrapper<TypeB>, TypeC> instance = my_map[type_a_instance];
```

This error triggers:

> no matching function for call to 'std::pair<std::reference_wrapper< TypeB>, TypeC>::pair()'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map::operator[]` must default construct the pair in the map if no mapping for the key exists. That's not possible for the types in your map because of the `reference_wrapper`. Use `find` instead.

```
pair<reference_wrapper<TypeB>, TypeC> instance = 
    my_map.find(type_a_instance)->second;
```

Or use `at` as suggested by @Steve Lorimer

```
pair<reference_wrapper<TypeB>, TypeC> instance = 
   my_map.at(type_a_instance);
```

Of course both versions assume that the key can be found. The `find` version gives you undefined behaviour if the key is not found, the `at` version gives a `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: or [`.at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at)

Comment: When using `std::map::find()`, simply check that the returned iterator is valid before dereferencing it, eg: `auto iter = my_map.find(type_a_instance); if (iter != my_map.end()) { auto &instance = iter->second; ... }`